# Rigging this arm- How can I do it?

Tags: armature

[image]

So basically I want to make this arm bend without deformation to the two main sections of the arm where the bones go through. To facilitate this I have two other areas (seen as triangles in the picture) which should expand or contract as the bone rotates round. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you show what it should give once bent? because bending is a deformation, so anyway you will have a deformation

Comment: Also, if you want your arm to have a particular shape once bent, you can use a shapekey with a driver so that the bone rotation controls the shapekey